# Functions in wordpress files (.php files)

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently took over a website that built by WordPress, I have never used WordPress before. And in the `.php` files I found some many functions like: `str_replace(),has_post_thumbnail()`, etc.

Could anybody tell me what are they and where to find them?

Comment: inside the Functions.php file :) [More Info Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained)

Comment: You should start by reading the documentation. Try Google. Trust me, you will find it.

Comment: thx a lot everybody. So these functions are generated by WP right? We normally dont need to modify them right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you dont need to change any of that in parent theme files.. If you want to change anything means, create a child theme and use it however you want..